# Retrieving a message from on_raw_reaction_add discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to make it so the bot removes the reaction using `discord.Message.remove_reaction()`, but I can't find a way to actually retrieve and store the message in a variable. Does anybody know how to do this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self):
    if self.message_id == 805179023641542726:
        channel = client.get_channel(self.channel_id)
        message = ???
        user = client.get_user(self.user_id)
        await message.remove_reaction(self.emoji,user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) returns a [`RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) which has a `message_id` attribute. You can pass it to [`discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message) to retreive the message :

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    user = client.get_user(payload.user_id)
    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji,user)
```

Reference : `discord.py` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)